# jqGrid Custom Grid Filter Reload

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, filter, reload

I'm using jqGrid to maintain a database in mysql through JSON data. I would like to have a filter reload the grid - inactive rows versus active rows. In my data url php file, where I connect to my database and feed it the initial query, I only pull columns where the `avail_ind = 'Y'` so all the data that is already in the grid are active records. So doing a search filter would not be the solution to the situation as that wouldn't find any records where `avail_ind = 'N'`.

I found Oleg's [demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CheckboxesWithVerticalHeaders1.htm) that something similar to what I'm looking for. I don't need the vertical headers that he demonstrates but mainly the Order Status box that contains check boxes to filter the grid data.

My main concern is since I'm initially pulling active records in the grid how can I feed the grid the parameters where avail_ind = 'N' or 'Y' to show all the possible records in the grid AND somehow link checkboxes or radio buttons to select which kind of records the user wants to view.

Thank you for your help.

---

**UPDATE**

jqGrid HTML/JavaScript code:
All code wasn't included for brevity

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
      jQuery("#grid").jqGrid("initFontAwesome").jqGrid({
          pager:'#gridpager', 
          url:'getDivisions.php',
          datatype: "json",
          mtype: 'GET',
          height: 300,
          width: 1000,
          showerrors:true,
          debug:true,

          colNames:['Div', 'L1L2', 'L2', 'L1L3', 'L2L3', 'Exec Begin', 'Exec End', 'CSA', 'Area Id','Short Desc','Enabled'],
          colModel:[
                    {name:'div_id',
                        index:'div_id', 
                        width:30,
                        editable:true,
                        sortable:false, 
                        resizable:false,
                        align:"center", 
                        editoptions:{size:2,maxlength:2},
                        editrules:{required:true,number:true},
                        formoptions:{elmprefix:"(*)"}
                     },

                    {name:'l1l2_id',
                        index:'l1l2_id',
                        width:30,
                        editable:true,
                        resizable:false,
                        sortable:false,
                        //formatter: nullFormatter,
                        editoptions:{size:4,maxlength:4},
                        editrules:{required:true,number:true},
                        formoptions:{elmprefix:"(*)"}

                    },

                    {name:'l2_id',
                        index:'l2_id', 
                        width:30,
                        editable:true,
                        resizable:false,
                        sortable:false,
                        align:"center",
                        editoptions:{size:2,maxlength:2},
                        editrules:{required:true,number:true},
                        formoptions:{elmprefix:"(*)"}
                    },
                    {name:'l1l3_id',
                        index:'l1l3_id', 
                        width:30,
                        editable:true,
                        resizable:false,
                        sortable:false,
                        editoptions:{size:5,maxlength:6,readonly:'readonly'},
                        editrules:{number:true}

                    },
                    {name:'l2l3_id',
                        index:'l2l3_id', 
                        width:30,
                        editable:true,
                        resizable:false,
                        sortable:false,
                        editoptions:{size:5,maxlength:4,readonly:'readonly'},
                        editrules:{number:true}
                    },
                    {name:'exec_beg',
                        index:'exec_beg', 
                        width:60,
                        editable:true,
                        resizable:false,
                        sortable:false,
                        editoptions:{size:10,maxlength:8,readonly:'readonly'},
                        editrules:{number:true}
                    },
                    {name:'exec_end',
                        index:'exec_end', 
                        width:50,
                        editable:true,
                        resizable:false,
                        sortable:false,
                        editoptions:{size:10,maxlength:8,readonly:'readonly'},
                        editrules:{number:true}
                    },
                    {name:'csa_id',
                        index:'csa_id', 
                        width:35,
                        editable:true,
                        resizable:false,
                        sortable:false,
                        editoptions:{size:5,maxlength:5},
                        editrules:{required:true},
                        formoptions:{elmprefix:"(*)"}
                    },
                    {name:'area_id',
                        index:'area_id',
                        width:40,
                        editable:true,
                        resizable:false,
                        sortable:false,
                        align:"center",
                        editoptions:{size:2,maxlength:2},
                        editrules:{number:true},
                        formoptions:{elmprefix:"(*)"}
                    },
                    {name:'short_desc',
                        index:'short_desc', 
                        width:60,
                        editable:true,
                        resizable:false,
                        sortable:false,
                        editoptions:{size:7,maxlength:10},
                        editrules:{required:true},
                        formoptions:{elmprefix:"(*)"}
                    },
                    {name:'avail_ind',
                        index:'avail_ind',
                        width:40,
                        editable:true,
                        resizable:false,
                        sortable:false,
                        align:"center",
                        edittype:"select",
                        editoptions:{value:"Y:Y;N:N"}}
                   ],

          viewrecords: true,
          sortorder: "asc",
          sortname: "div_id",
          caption:"Division Codes",
          editurl:'editdivisions.php',
          toppager:true, 
          recordtext:'', 
          hidegrid:false, 
          scroll:true,
          rowNum:"10000"

     }); //jQuery("#grid").jqGrid
```

GetDivisions.php code: retrieves the data to load the grid

```
<?php 
    $dbhost = "localhost"; 
    $dbuser = "root"; 
    $dbpass = "*********"; 
    $dbname = "CodeTable"; 


    $page = $_GET['page']; // get the requested page
    $limit = $_GET['rows']; // get how many rows we want to have into the grid
    $sidx = $_GET['sidx']; // get index row - i.e. user click to sort
    $sord = $_GET['sord']; // get the direction

    if(!$sidx) $sidx =1;

    // connect to the database
    $db = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("Connection Error: " . mysql_error());

    mysql_select_db($dbname) or die("Error conecting to db.");
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT div_id, l1l2_id, l2_id, l1l3_id, l2l3_id, exec_beg, exec_end, csa_id, area_id, short_desc, avail_ind FROM divcodes where div_id <> "  " and avail_ind = "Y" and active_ind="Y"');
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC);
    $count = $row['count'];

    if( $count >0 ) 
    {
        $total_pages = cell($count/$limit);
    } 
    else 
    {
            $total_pages = 0;
    }

    if ($page > $total_pages) $page=$total_pages;
    $start = $limit*$page - $limit; // do not put $limit*($page - 1)
    $SQL = 'SELECT div_id, l1l2_id, l2_id, l1l3_id, l2l3_id, exec_beg, exec_end, csa_id, area_id, short_desc, avail_ind FROM divcodes where div_id <> "  " and avail_ind = "Y" and active_ind="Y"';
    $result = mysql_query( $SQL ) or die("Couldn t execute query.".mysql_error());

    $response->page = $page;
    $response->total = $total_pages;
    $response->records = $count;

    $i=0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $response->rows[$i]['id']=$row[div_id];
        $response->rows[$i]['cell']=array($row[div_id],$row[l1l2_id],$row[l2_id],$row[l1l2_id],$row[l2l3_id],$row[exec_beg],$row[exec_end],$row[csa_id],$row[area_id],$row[short_desc],$row[avail_ind]);
        $i++;
    }        
    echo json_encode($response);

    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you do not hard-code your server side query on your data, but rather let jqGrid tell your server what it is looking for.

This would be accomplished by setting up a radio button element(s) or checkbox, etc. as part of your webpage.  Then on the page load you can help form the request jqGrid sends out, and then resends when the element(s) that you have setup change in state.

Ex:

```
element.ChangeEvent()( function () {
    var grid = $('#gridName');

grid.jqGrid('setGridParam', { search: false });
var postData = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'postData');
    $.extend(postData, { filters: "" });

var f = { groupOp: "AND", rules: [] };

    f.rules.push({ field: "avail_ind", op: "eq", data: $(selectedElementName).val() });
    grid.jqGrid('setGridParam', { search: true });
}
JSON.stringify(f) : "")}

                                        });
    grid.jqGrid().trigger('reloadGrid', [{ page: 1}]);

});
```

As part of this when you are originally setting up the jqGrid you are setting the `search: true` and the filter as part of the grid setup so it shows the acurate data to start, and then the changing user preference as the element you setup changes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Mark, I see that you are suggesting to not hard-code the query but please see my update on how I retrieve the JSON data from the database in order to load the grid. I'm just not fully understanding the code in your example.

Comment: @klm10 Ah, sorry but I'm not a PHP guy, but where you are building your query string, make it dynamic based on what the jqGrid passes to your server.  Specifically so you can dynamically change the `avail_ind = "Y"` part of your query.  If you are not using jqGrid to format the query for your database, you can just use a `postData` parameter to let your server decide how to format the db query string.

Comment: @klm10 Glad I could help.  Really this will add a ton of functionality to your jqGrids and make them much more dynamic and improve your users experience.  Please mark correct if this was the solution.